# Do current browsers accept cookies from an ajax response?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, browser

If I return a cookie with a response which is triggered by an ajax request, would the browser save the cookie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, from: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

> If the user agent supports HTTP State Management it should persist, discard and send cookies (as received in the Set-Cookie response header, and sent in the Cookie header) as applicable. [COOKIES]

Comment: But is this true for cross-domain AJAX?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the browser will save the cookie you've created in the ajax request - it doesn't matter if your request was via ajax or you've reloaded the page. It's still a REQUEST :)